# Can I add/replace the Wordpress image in the Dashboard

Tags: customization, dashboard

Is it possible to change the Wordpress logo and header in the Dashboard so I can customise it a little more to my business? Ideally it could be done in a way so that it wouldn't break every time I upgrade Wordpress to the latest version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

baritoneuk - There are several plugin which can handle the branding as well as code which removes the need for the plugin.

For a plugin, I recommend [White Label CMS](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/white-label-cms/), if you're feeling adventurous try this [article from WP Beginner](http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/25-extremely-useful-tricks-for-the-wordpress-functions-file/)

Comment: Brilliant, the White Label CMS looks just like what I need!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, admin customization is possible though the details are not really flushed out much anywhere except existing code.

Basically, you [enqueue styles](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_style) and use the "cascading" part of CSS to override selectors and other CSS elements. Try checking out how plugins like [this one](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/ozh-admin-drop-down-menu/) do it.